# Is $f( x + iy) = e^{-x} e^{-iy}$ complex - differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I started by letting $u(x,y) = e^{-x}$ and $v(x,y) = e^{-iy}$ . I then tried to use the cauchy reiman equations : $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$. But my answer did not seem right, did I assign my values of $u$ and $v$ correctly?

Comment: No you did not. You can immediately tell that something is wrong, because both u and v must be real.

Comment: Your $v$ is not the imaginary part of $f$.

Comment: Let $z=x+iy$, then $e^{-x}e^{-iy}=e^{-x-iy}=e^{-(x+iy)}=e^{-z}$. So since $e^{-z}$ is entire (as it's shown in the answer below), your function is entire as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your decomposition is wrong. You need to find real-valued functions $u(x, y)$ and $v(x, y)$ so that $f(x + iy) = u(x, y) + i v(x, y)$.

Note
$$f(x + iy) = e^{-x} e^{-iy} = e^{-x}(\cos(-y) + i \sin(-y)) = e^{-x} \cos(-y) + i e^{-x} \sin(-y)$$
i.e. $u(x, y) = e^{-x} \cos(-y)$ and $v(x, y) = e^{-x} \sin(-y)$. You can now easily verify that the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold everywhere.

Comment: Ah thank you, I should have seen the expansion for $e^{-iy}$!

Comment: How would I then determine, whether f(x+iy) is homomorphic?

Comment: This depends on which definition/ characterization of hoplomorphy you want to use.

Comment: sorry i meant to type holomorphic, and i am wanting to find whether the function is holomorphic and if so where it is.

Comment: Yes, that's why you need to tell us your definition of holomorphy. There are various equivalent characterizations, which one do you want to use?

Comment: I have been given two: let $G \subseteq  \mathbb{C}$ be open . A function $f$ is said to be holomorphic on G if f is differentiable at all $z \in G$.

Comment: and: A function $f$ of a complex variable is said to be holomorphic at a point $a \in \mathbb{c}$ if $f$ is holomorphic on $D(a;r)$ for some $r$.

Comment: Well check conditions on when a complex function is differentiable. You essentially just need to verify the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Yea I figured that out in the end :). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Remark that $f(z)=e^{-z}$ is analytic:
$$
e^{-z} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k z^k}{k!}.
$$
Hence it must be differentiable. However, the real part of $e^{-iy}$ is $\cos y$, so that your $v$ is wrong. The real part of $f$ is $u(x,y)=-e^{-x} \cos y$.